# Issue With Updating Pandas Dataframe Column Based on Reference Table Targeting Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to update based on information that I have in an external reference table (that is currently a small ~20 entry csv), and I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to get it to work.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
id    company    value1    value2
1     foo        10.00     0.00
2     bar        10.00     0.00
3     lorem      15.00     0.00
4     ipsum      10.00     0.00
5     foo        50.00     0.00
6     lorem      40.00     0.00
7     foo        0.00      0.00
```

The reference table csv contains percentages to multiply value1 by to get value2, like this (they were originally decimals, but vd = pd.read_csv('$name.csv', index_col=0).to_dict() was causing floating point issues, so I changed the reference table instead):

```
company   percentage
foo       15
bar       50
ipsum     40
```

I am looking for the output to appear as the following:

```
id    company    value1    value2
1     foo        10.00     1.50
2     bar        10.00     5.00
3     lorem      15.00     15.00
4     ipsum      10.00     4.00
5     foo        50.00     7.50
6     lorem      40.00     40.00
7     foo        0.00      0.00
```

At the moment, I am importing the reference table into a dictionary (as integers), however when I go to match it against the dataframe, the results (value2) come back as NaN. I think my issue might be with the matching code, which currently looks like this:

```
df['value2'] = df['value1'] * (df["company"].map(vd)/100)
```

Am I on the right track here? This is my first time using pandas, so I might be missing something obvious.

Thank you!

edit: accidentally forgot to obfuscate one variable. "vd" was just the name of the dictionary once it was imported.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood before. Can you show what `vd` is? If it is a DataFrame, instead of `vd` you can use `vd.set_index('company')['percentage']` but you need to show how you are constructing those.

Comment: No, you seem to have been right before. Getting rid of the dictionary and instead using vd = pd.read_csv('$name.csv', index_col=0, squeeze=True) fixed the issue for the ones that were in the reference table, and I don't care about the ones that weren't in the reference table (because they're getting dropped right after). Now I just need to add bounds checking (as anything negative in one earlier section needs to be 0 instead of negative) and then it's good to go. Thank you!

Comment: Would encourage you to look through my answer as well ;-)

Comment: Yep. It was quite interesting as well. Already upovted it, but it says that it won't show up until I get over a certain reputation threshold. I guess that's what I get for only lurking until now. I'll have to come back to it after I get this up and running to see if I can work some of those suggestions in to improve it further!

Comment: Please see my comment above. ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is by far the fastest way to do what you're doing. But here are a couple of alternatives, along with their performance.

**Setup**

First, `df` -

```
df

   id company  value1  value2
0   1     foo    10.0     0.0
1   2     bar    10.0     0.0
2   3   lorem    15.0     0.0
3   4   ipsum    10.0     0.0
4   5     foo    50.0     0.0
5   6   lorem    40.0     0.0
```

Next, `vd` -

```
vd = pd.read_csv('$name.csv')
vd = vd.set_index('company').percentage
```

Or,

```
vd = pd.read_csv('$name.csv', index_col=0, squeeze=True)  # @ayhan's suggestion
```

```
vd

company
foo      15
bar      50
ipsum    40
Name: percentage, dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 1**
*`map`*

```
df.value2 = df.value1 * df.company.map(vd).fillna(100).div(100)
df

   id company  value1  value2
0   1     foo    10.0     1.5
1   2     bar    10.0     5.0
2   3   lorem    15.0    15.0
3   4   ipsum    10.0     4.0
4   5     foo    50.0     7.5
5   6   lorem    40.0    40.0
```

---

**Option 2**
*`replace`*

```
v = pd.to_numeric(df.company.replace(vd), errors='coerce')
df.value2 = df.value1 * v.fillna(100) / 100
df

   id company  value1  value2
0   1     foo    10.0     1.5
1   2     bar    10.0     5.0
2   3   lorem    15.0    15.0
3   4   ipsum    10.0     4.0
4   5     foo    50.0     7.5
5   6   lorem    40.0    40.0
```

---

**Option 3**
*`merge`*

```
df = df.merge(
     (vd / 100).to_frame(), 
     left_on='company', 
     right_index=True, 
     how='left'
).fillna(1)

df.value2 = df.value1 * df.percentage 
del df['percentage']

df

   id company  value1  value2
0   1     foo    10.0     1.5
1   2     bar    10.0     5.0
2   3   lorem    15.0    15.0
3   4   ipsum    10.0     4.0
4   5     foo    50.0     7.5
5   6   lorem    40.0    40.0
```

---

**Performance**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%timeit df.value1 * df.company.map(vd).fillna(100).div(100)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.07 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df.value1 * pd.to_numeric(df.company.replace(vd), errors='coerce').fillna(100) / 100
10 loops, best of 3: 65.6 ms per loop
```

```
%%timeit
df2 = df.merge((vd / 100).to_frame(), left_on='company', right_index=True, how='left').fillna(1)
df2.value2 = df2.value1 * df2.percentage 
del df2['percentage']

100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop
```

`map` is the clear winner here.